# How to scroll to my button? .scrollTo() not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[There is my page](http://crelation.com/freeMag/lazyload)

Just a simple photo viewer.

But i don't know how to scroll down/up via my button.

I tried to use jquery .scrollTo(y-offset), but it doesn't work.

Here is my function:

```
function ScrollDown() {
        var $chapters = $('#dContent').children('.sContent');
        var $chScrollPositions = new Array();

        $chapters.each(function (i) {
            $chScrollPositions[i] = Math.round($(this).offset().top - $('#dContent').offset().top) - 10;
            //alert($chScrollPositions[i]);
        });

        var last = $chapters.parent().find('.active').removeClass('active').index();

        var next = (last + 1 == $chapters.length) ? 0 : last + 1; // Loop around to first chapter
        $chapters.eq(next).addClass('active'); // Set Next Chapter Active
        $('#dContnet').scrollTo($chScrollPositions[next]);
    }
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: You know you have Javascript errors on your page ?? On .scrollTo line :
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: looking at chrome developer tool, it says `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` referring to line `$('#img-wrapper-tmpl').tmpl( {itemsCount : itemsCount} ).appendTo( $rgGallery );` - you may want to fix that first...

Comment: I really don't know that!! I will check it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) to do that

```
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: 1000}, 300);
```